# Ошибка SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python

При установке бота на `pythonanywhere` я прописываю `pip3.6 install --user pytelegrambotapi`, после пишу `cd bot` и запускаю бота `python tes.py`, но после у меня появляется ошибка. Я проверил строку 89 но ошибки не нашел.
Вот код ошибки:

```
File "tes.py", line 89
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Номер {message.text} - уже есть в белом листе")
                                                                                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Выложите код, чтобы вам могли дать ответ.

Comment: Проверь предыдущую, там не закрыта скобка.